# ArrayAdapter giving error when trying to use it with ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

So after hours of trying to figure out the problem, trying different tests, I can't seem to figure out what the error is. Whenever I enter a search string, and this method runs, I get two errors. 1 is that in the for loop where i compare strings, I seem to get a StringIndexOutOfBounds, and the ListView gives me a NullPointerException from the ArrayAdapter

Code:

```
 public void search(String[] s)
{
    setContentView(R.layout.search);
    final EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchBox);
    Button go = (Button)findViewById(R.id.go);
    final int sizeString = s.length;
    final String[] a = new String[sizeString];
    for(int i = 0;i<sizeString;i++)
        a[i] = s[i];
    go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick (View v)
        {
            List<String> li = new ArrayList<String>();
            String entered = text.getText().toString().trim();
            String[] query = entered.split(" ");
            int temp;
            for (int i = 0; i < sizeString;i++)
            {
                temp = a[i].indexOf(" ");
                if (query[0].toLowerCase().equalsIgnoreCase(a[i].substring(0, temp).toLowerCase()))
                    li.add(a[i]);
            }
            setContentView(R.layout.search_results);
            final ListView list= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.search_list);
            String[] results = new String[sizeString];
            for(int i = 0; i<li.size();i++)
                results[i]=li.get(i);
            list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Browse.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,results));
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: What is the temp value you are getting? I think that value is greater than your a[i] string length. I would suggest add some System.out (or) Log there. Once this is fixed, we can check second issue.

Comment: the temp value is just so i can extract the first word from a large list of words through which I'm trying to search through. I'm just using it has the first time i get a " ". That shouldn't be causing a problem... or should it :S

Comment: Two possibilities, either a[i] might be empty string (or) temp value is greater than a[i] length. One of these causing StringindexOutofBound Exception.

Comment: The string a is not an empty string because the values are all inputted into strings.xml, which I put in myself. I think the temp value might be greater for some of the strings... could it be because some strings are single words? Im not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Just breakpoint your code and go through it step by step. At the least provide some more information on which line(s) the errors occur.

Comment: Can you paste here what are the values in String[] s?

Comment: The error is coming on this line:
if (query[0].toLowerCase().equalsIgnoreCase(a[i].substring(0, temp).toLowerCase()))

Comment: I know. query[0] , a[i] all are derived from String[] s, if you observe properly.

Comment: No query is from the EditText, the textbox.

Comment: sorry,you are correct, but a[i] is from String[] s, which is the one causing the problem.